# Rails generate migration does not set :null => false to created_at and update_at

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I created a brand new rails app, generate some scaffolds and some models. After few tests i realized that the columns generated by t.timestamps does not include the "traditional" :null => false option. I need this behaviour, i can't see what is doing this.

I recreate a new app, thinking that's a new rails 4 functionality, but i can't get the save behaviour. In this app the timespamp work as it should.

In the "bugging app" in a rails console when i create a post we can see :

```
Loading development environment (Rails 4.0.1)

2.0.0-p247 :001 > Post.create(title:"test") 

(0.1ms)  begin transaction SQL (8.6ms)  INSERT INTO "posts" ("created_at", "title", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Wed, 27 Nov 2013 21:19:01 EST -05:00], ["title", "test"], ["updated_at", Wed, 27 Nov 2013 21:19:01 EST -05:00]]
(0.8ms)  commit transaction
=> #<Post id: 1, title: "test", content: nil, excerpt: nil, dashboard: nil, created_at: "2013-11-28 02:19:01", updated_at: "2013-11-28 02:19:01"> 

2.0.0-p247 :002 > Post.last

Post Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" ORDER BY "posts"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
=> #<Post id: 1, title: "test", content: nil, excerpt: nil, dashboard: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

The Timestamp is set but not save in the database.

I think i'm missing something. Any idea how to restore the default behaviour?

EDIT: migration file

```
class CreatePosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :posts do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.text :content
      t.text :excerpt
      t.boolean :dashboard

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you post your migration files here?

Comment: Done. But nothing special there. I never add the :null => false option on timestamp by myself rails was handling this.

Comment: 2 years ago a change was made to make these not null. See https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/3334/files. You may find something useful in there. Were you using the same version of rails where it 'worked' versus where it doesn't work?

Comment: I just switch to rails 4. I was using 3.2.14 in my last app. What is strange is when i saw this error happening i tried to generate another new rails 4 app and the behaviour was not the same. I don't understand.

Comment: Ok that is not so old. All I can suggest is debugging activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_definitions.rb and see what is going on, it may shed some light. Also try dropping the database and doing a migrate it and see what it does too.

Comment: I tried dropping and recreating the migrations without success. It's very strange. ps: thanks for trying to help me !

Comment: It´s definitly specific to this app. I dont understand why these attributes aren't save on creation.

Comment: I try again to build a new app and the behaviour of timestamp is ok. There are no :null => false option in the schema but the timestamps works normaly and the infos are saved in the database. What can cause the timestamp not working as it should on my first app?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally I found the error:

After few attempts i check everything in the config dir. The only possibility i saw for a timestamp was the time zone configuration.

After commenting this (config/application.rb):

```
#config.active_record.default_timezone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'
```

Everything was back to normal! No more :null => false, but timestamp was able to record in the database.