# My records Timestamps values are shown nil on rails 4.2.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, ruby-on-rails-4.2, rspec3

After upgrading a rails 3.2 app to Rails 4.2.3 and Rspec-rails to 3 many test started failing, many of them because its code relies on `created_at`attribute and after inspecting the code on the console I notices the timestamps values are both nil.

I'm not sure what's going on.
Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Are you saving the records before trying to access `created_at` ?

Comment: for future readers. This is the problem and solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20256989/rails-generate-migration-does-not-set-null-false-to-created-at-and-update-at